# Compose up stuck at "Attaching to", using --verbose doesn't show any information

Tags: docker

When running `sudo docker compose --verbose up`, I'm getting just this below:

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                        
Attaching to mycontainer
```

I expected to get some extra information adding `--verbose` option but I don't get anything more.

I'm using Docker 24 on Ubuntu 20.